# Navigation property is always null when using Include with EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these entities:

```
public class Portfolio : EntityBase<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class Client : EntityBase<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
}
```

And have a repository method that looks like this:

```
private readonly EnisDbContext _enisDbContext;

public IEnumerable<Portfolio> SearchPortfolios(Expression<Func<Portfolio, bool>> criteria, bool includeClients = false)
{
    IQueryable<Portfolio> portfolios = _enisDbContext.Portfolios;
    if (includeClients)
    {
        portfolios.Include(c => c.Client);
    }

    return portfolios.Where(criteria);
}
```

But when I call SearchPortfolios, the Client navigation property on Portfolio is always null:

```
var viewModels = _clientRepository
                    .SearchPortfolios(c => true, includeClients: true)
                    .Select(c => new ViewModels.Portfolio()
                    {
                        Name = c.Name,
                        Id = c.Id,
                        ClientName = c.Client.Name // Null Reference Exception
                    }).ToList();
```

I've used .Include() in a similar way in other places in my application at it has worked fine. I'm using EF Core 2.2.4 with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
portfolios.Include(c => c.Client);
```

this should really be

```
portfolios = portfolios.Include(c => c.Client);
```

without assigning it to the current portfolios query it wont be persisting that .include into it

Comment: Silly me. Thank you